# How to saveAsTable to Hive (so that the Hive table is MANAGED_TABLE)?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When I try saving a table without an explicit path, the hivemetastore will have a bogus "path" property pointing to "/user/hive/warehouse" instead of "/hive/warehouse". If I *explicitly* set the path to what I want using .option("path", "/hive/warehouse") then everything works but Hive creates an external table. Is there a way to save a managed table to the hive metastore and not have that bogus path property that does not match the location of the files in hive?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master(master_url).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

df = spark.range(100)

df.write.saveAsTable("test1")
df.write.option("path", "/hive/warehouse").saveAsTable("test2")

hive> describe formatted test1;
OK
# col_name              data_type               comment             

id                      bigint                                      

# Detailed Table Information         
Database:               default                  
Owner:                  root                     
CreateTime:             Fri Mar 10 18:53:07 UTC 2017     
LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN                  
Protect Mode:           None                     
Retention:              0                        
Location:               file:/hive/warehouse/test1 
Table Type:             MANAGED_TABLE            
Table Parameters:        
    spark.sql.sources.provider  parquet             
    spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts   1                   
    spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0 {\"type\":\"struct\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"long\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}}]}
    transient_lastDdlTime   1489171987          

# Storage Information        
SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe  
InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat    
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat   
Compressed:             No                       
Num Buckets:            -1                       
Bucket Columns:         []                       
Sort Columns:           []                       
Storage Desc Params:         
    path                    file:/user/hive/warehouse/test1
    serialization.format    1                   
Time taken: 0.423 seconds, Fetched: 30 row(s)


hive> describe formatted test2;
OK
# col_name              data_type               comment             

id                      bigint                                      

# Detailed Table Information         
Database:               default                  
Owner:                  root                     
CreateTime:             Fri Mar 10 16:02:07 UTC 2017     
LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN                  
Protect Mode:           None                     
Retention:              0                        
Location:               file:/hive/warehouse/test2   
Table Type:             EXTERNAL_TABLE           
Table Parameters:        
    COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE   false               
    EXTERNAL                TRUE                
    numFiles                2                   
    numRows                 -1                  
    rawDataSize             -1                  
    spark.sql.sources.provider  parquet             
    spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts   1                   
    spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0 {\"type\":\"struct\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"long\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}}]}
    totalSize               4755                
    transient_lastDdlTime   1489161727          

# Storage Information        
SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe  
InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat    
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat   
Compressed:             No                       
Num Buckets:            -1                       
Bucket Columns:         []                       
Sort Columns:           []                       
Storage Desc Params:         
    path                    file:/hive/warehouse/test2
    serialization.format    1                   
Time taken: 0.402 seconds, Fetched: 36 row(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue. For people out there with similar issues I'll post my fix.

This issue with the "path" param being incorrect only came up when saving tables into the default hive database (as shown below). This made me think that maybe "old" databases were using the old configuration value (hive.metastore.warehouse.dir) while new databases were using the new value.

Thus, the fix was to drop the default database, recreate the database, and now all databases created in the hive metastore will use the correct value of hive.metastore.warehouse.dir.

```
spark.sql("create database testdb")
spark.sql("use testdb")
df.write.saveAsTable("test3")

hive> describe formatted test.test3;
OK
# col_name              data_type               comment             

id                      bigint                                      

# Detailed Table Information         
Database:               testdb                   
Owner:                  root                     
CreateTime:             Fri Mar 10 22:10:10 UTC 2017     
LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN                  
Protect Mode:           None                     
Retention:              0                        
Location:               file:/hive/warehouse/test.db/test3   
Table Type:             MANAGED_TABLE            
Table Parameters:        
    COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE   false               
    numFiles                1                   
    numRows                 -1                  
    rawDataSize             -1                  
    spark.sql.sources.provider  parquet             
    spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts   1                   
    spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0 {\"type\":\"struct\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"long\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}}]}
    totalSize               409                 
    transient_lastDdlTime   1489183810          

# Storage Information        
SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe  
InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat    
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat   
Compressed:             No                       
Num Buckets:            -1                       
Bucket Columns:         []                       
Sort Columns:           []                       
Storage Desc Params:         
    path                    file:/hive/warehouse/test.db/test3
    serialization.format    1                   
Time taken: 0.243 seconds, Fetched: 35 row(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

> **hive.metastore.warehouse.dir**
>
> - Default Value: /user/hive/warehouse
> - Added In: Hive 0.2.0
>
>   Location of default database for the warehouse.
>
> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties

Comment: I configured that property in hive-site.xml (on both the hive metastore node and all the spark nodes) and made it point to /hive/warehouse. If you look at the describe table commands above, hive even respects this path in the 'location' property but not the 'path' property. I guess I'm not sure what the difference between the location and path properties is.